# Mistakenly shooting one of the wrong group of balls in 8-ball

Tags: rules

In 8-ball after ball groups have been designated.(no longer open table), A player mistakenly calls a shot and pockets his apponent's ball but "Foul" was not called. The offending player then called a second shot and pocketed another ball from his apponent's group of balls. This time Foul was called. My question is what rule prevails?

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on what rules you are playing with, but typically if no one notices a previous foul before the next shot is made, it is no longer relevant. [Here is an example of this rule](http://upatour.com/official-billiard-rules/u-s-8-ball-rules/):

> **11.1 Wrong Balls Pocketed**
>
> When it is discovered that the shooting player has been shooting the opponent’s designated ball(s) as if it were their own, the shooter shall relinquish the table with a ball in hand foul to the opponent (see 7.3, Bad Hit).